# Below query is taking 2 mins ,can it be tuned more

Tags: sql++

Help me tune below query:
SELECT META(m).id, m.sch_name AS name FROM `pricing_qa_1` AS m
 UNNEST m.pri_sch_ref AS r WHERE m.dtype = "mprisch" AND r 
 IN( SELECT  RAW META(a).id FROM `pricing_qa_1` AS a UNNEST a.prod_prof AS p WHERE a.dtype = "prisch" AND (p.prod_cd = "WMOBAC000A1") ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array indexing with ANSI JOIN described here https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/ (Example 12, 13, 14)

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON pricing_qa_1 ( DISTINCT v.prod_cd FOR v IN prod_prof END ) WHEERE dtype = "prisch";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON pricing_qa_1 ( DISTINCT pri_sch_ref ) WHEERE dtype = "mprisch";

SELECT META(m).id , m.sch_name AS name
FROM pricing_qa_1 AS p
JOIN pricing_qa_1 AS m
ON ANY mv IN m.pri_sch_ref SATISFIES mv = META(p).id END AND m.dtype = "mprisch"
WHERE p.dtype = "prisch" AND ANY v IN p.prod_prof SATISFIES v.prod_cd = "WMOBAC000A1" END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array in each document, and you are interested in the documents where the array contains the prod_id value "WMOBAC000A1". Is that right?

You should be able to do away with the UNNESTs completely, using an ANY operator:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html